# How to ensure that one OpenMP parallel section doesn't impact another one?

Tags: c++, c, windows, openmp

I have written a basic program that will slow its FPS to around 60 FPS by entering a while loop and comparing the time within the loop to the time before it starts, then it will output the FPS to the console.

In the same program, I have another block of code that will slow the FPS to around 10 FPS using similar methods.

What I am trying to do is using OpenMP to execute **both** blocks of code in parallel in such a way that the 10 FPS block doesn't *slow down* or *interfere* with the 60FPS block. My ultimate goal is to get the 60 FPS block runing at 60 FPS, even though there is a loop in the program that would otherwise bring it down to 10 FPS.

I have tried using several different combinations of OpenMP directives to get this to happen, but no matter what directives I use, the program always seems to end up running at 10 FPS.

Is it possible to get this to work with OpenMP?

Here is the code:
(edit: I have removed the race condition mentioned by dreamcrash and fixed some other errors I noticed)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    
    // Get the QueryPerformance frequency to measure the FPS
    LARGE_INTEGER PerfCountFrequencyResult;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&PerfCountFrequencyResult);
    int64_t PerfCountFrequency = PerfCountFrequencyResult.QuadPart;
    
    // 10 FPS for first thread
    double Thread1TargetSecondsPerFrame = 1.0f / (double)10;
    
    // 60 FPS for second thread
    double Thread2TargetSecondsPerFrame = 1.0f / (double)60;
        
    // Get Current time
    LARGE_INTEGER LastCounter;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&LastCounter);
    
    
    while(1){
        #pragma omp parallel sections
        {
            // THREAD 1 (very slow 10FPS)
            #pragma omp section
            {
                // Remove race condition
                double SecondsElapsedForFrame;
                
                // Get the seconds elapsed since last loop
                LARGE_INTEGER CurrentCounter;
                QueryPerformanceCounter(&CurrentCounter);
                SecondsElapsedForFrame = ((float)(CurrentCounter.QuadPart - LastCounter.QuadPart) / (float)PerfCountFrequency);
                
                // DELAY The time until it's 10FPS
                if(SecondsElapsedForFrame < Thread1TargetSecondsPerFrame) {
                    while(SecondsElapsedForFrame < Thread1TargetSecondsPerFrame) {
                        // Get the seconds elapsed since last loop
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(&CurrentCounter);
                        SecondsElapsedForFrame = ((float)(CurrentCounter.QuadPart - LastCounter.QuadPart) / (float)PerfCountFrequency);
                    }           
                }
                
            }
            
            // THEAD 2 (should not be interrupted by THREAD 1)
            #pragma omp section
            {
                // Remove race condition
                double SecondsElapsedForFrame;
                
                // Get the seconds elapsed since last loop
                LARGE_INTEGER CurrentCounter;
                QueryPerformanceCounter(&CurrentCounter);
                SecondsElapsedForFrame = ((float)(CurrentCounter.QuadPart - LastCounter.QuadPart) / (float)PerfCountFrequency);
                
                // DELAY the time until it's 60FPS
                if(SecondsElapsedForFrame < Thread2TargetSecondsPerFrame) {
                    while(SecondsElapsedForFrame < Thread2TargetSecondsPerFrame) {
                        // Get the seconds elapsed since last loop
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(&CurrentCounter);
                        SecondsElapsedForFrame = ((float)(CurrentCounter.QuadPart - LastCounter.QuadPart) / (float)PerfCountFrequency);
                    }                   
                }
                
                // Get the seconds elapsed and output the FPS
                QueryPerformanceCounter(&CurrentCounter);       
                double SecondsPerFrame = ((float)(CurrentCounter.QuadPart - LastCounter.QuadPart) / (float)PerfCountFrequency);
                float FramesPerSecond = 1.0f/ SecondsPerFrame;
                std::cout << "FPS:" << FramesPerSecond << "\n";
                
                
                // Get new time for beginning of loop
                QueryPerformanceCounter(&LastCounter);  
            }
            
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You use the same `SecondsPerFrame` variable to get your program FPS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Read the OpenMP specification of the `sections` directive (https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu42.html#x66-660002.10.1), and consider its synchronisation properties. Also, consider when the parallel region can end, and what rate that implies for the execution of all of the sections...

Answer (score 1):

First code for *correctness*, and then for *performance*.

Your OpenMP program is *ill-formed* as it contains a **race condition** on `SecondsElapsedForFrame`. Indeed, the variable is implicitly shared in the parallel region between the two threads and both write into it. The same also applies to `LastCounter`. You probably want to make them `private`, `firstprivate` or `lastprivate` depending on your needs.

Comment: I have opted to declare the SecondsElapsedForFrame separately in each OMP thread. I believe that removes the race condition. 

I'm not sure how LastCounter is also causing a race condition as it is only written into by one of the threads. The other thread just reads its data. Does it still cause a race condition?

Comment: `LastCounter` is written at the end of thread 2 but read by both. This means that if thread 2 finish his work while thread 1 is still working, thread 1 will be effected. The result is not deterministic. If you want to use this variable to communicate between threads, you need synchronization directives (critical section, barriers, etc.), otherwise you need to control the access of the variable like you did for `SecondsElapsedForFrame`.

Comment: Beside this, please do not overwrite the code of your question: write an update text so this can help future readers to understand the problem and the answer. If the problem is still there, you can precise this in the update, or comment the question. If the problem is solved, there is no need for additional updates: just mark the question as solved.